# How do I import a global provider into another global provider in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I want to import the config provider from the documentation into another provider.

I am using the same config structure that is sown in the documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration).

So the `config.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Module, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useValue: new ConfigService(
        `config/env/${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'}.env`,
      ),
    },
  ],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

And the other provider should look something like this correct?

`token.module.ts`

```
import { Module, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TokenService} from './token.service';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  import: [ConfigService]
  providers: [TokenService],
  exports: [TokenService],
})
export class TokenModule {}
```

While the TokenService should look something like this

`token.service.ts`

```
import { ConfigService } from '../../config/config.service';

export class TokenService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  test(): string {
    return this.configService.get('TestVal');
  }
}
```

But when I import TokenModule in AppModule I get this error `The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mark your `TokenService` as `@Injectable()`. You need to tell NestJS about arguments that need to be provided to other services.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed one of the issues. But I was importing TokenModule instead of the TokenService. Adding TokenService ti the providers array in app.module.ts works now.